# pyarrow.csv.read_csv() memory high and not released after execute function in JupyterLab

Tags: pandas, pyarrow

The memory not released after execute load_csv_by_arrow() function on JupyterLab. This seems only happen in JupyterLab not other IDE and the memory seems increase a little bit every time the function runs.

```
from pyarrow import csv

def load_csv_by_arrow():
    table = csv.read_csv(r'./data/xxx.csv')
    df = table.to_pandas()
    del df

# in JupyterLab cell
%memit load_csv_by_arrow()
```

- Window Server 2016
- pandas:2.0.0
- pyarrow:11.0.0
- jupyterlab: 3.6.3

in Jupyterlab by execute cell as `!python load_csv_by_arrow.py` doesn't increase the memory. And pa.total_allocated_bytes() show there is no memory allocate for pyarrow object. then what is the high memory in jupyterlab for ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try clearing the cache by restarting the kernel or using the `gc.collect()`method. This will do two things, 1) clear the cache and 2) clear past object references.

If that doesn't work you can try using the `memory_profiler` library to profile the memory usage of your function and identify where the memory is being allocated.

Comment: I have tried `gc.collect()` , `%reset -f out`, `%reset -f in` , neither of them reduce the memory. And by using `memory_profiler`  to run `%mprun load_csv_by_arrow load_csv_by_arrow()` it shows 800M+ memory incremental on line `table = csv.read_csv(r'./data/xxx.csv')`, the problems is  it is inside the function, and it should release memory after function running. But seems it doesn't release memory.  `psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 1024**2` shows the memory increase from 200M to 1G+ after running, but `pa.total_allocated_bytes()` show there is no memory allocate for pyarrow object.